# Folders and files visible only with command line

Tags: windows-7, ntfs

I installed mpmath manually (via setup.py), then installed sympy (via pip). Now contents of folder "G:\Old\pypy\site-packages" in Explorer looks like this:

```
mpmath
mpmath-0.19-py2.7.egg-info
README
```

and command

> dir

shows this:

```
30.10.2016  13:54    <DIR>          .
30.10.2016  13:54    <DIR>          ..
30.10.2016  13:54    <DIR>          mpmath
30.10.2016  13:54               342 mpmath-0.19-py2.7.egg-info
24.10.2016  14:17               119 README
30.10.2016  13:59               126 easy_install.py
30.10.2016  13:59               347 easy_install.pyc
30.10.2016  13:59    <DIR>          pip
30.10.2016  13:59    <DIR>          pip-8.1.2.dist-info
30.10.2016  13:59    <DIR>          pkg_resources
30.10.2016  13:59    <DIR>          setuptools
30.10.2016  13:59    <DIR>          setuptools-28.7.1.dist-info
30.10.2016  14:12    <DIR>          sympy
30.10.2016  14:12    <DIR>          sympy-1.0-py2.7.egg-info
30.10.2016  13:59    <DIR>          wheel
30.10.2016  13:59    <DIR>          wheel-0.29.0.dist-info
```

"Hide protected system files" is unchecked and "show hidden files folders and drives" is checked. What is the cause of this and how to fix it?

result of "attrib" command:

```
G:\Old\pypy\site-packages>attrib
A            G:\Old\pypy\site-packages\mpmath-0.19-py2.7.egg-info
A            G:\Old\pypy\site-packages\README
A            G:\Old\pypy\site-packages\easy_install.py
A            G:\Old\pypy\site-packages\easy_install.pyc
```

Comment: Can you type the command `attrib` in a command prompt that folder and post its results here too?

Comment: @LPChip: done...

Comment: I can't explain this. Its almost like explorer uses a cached version. Have you rebooted your pc since?

Comment: Rebooted. Sorry, I was wrong. files are still there and hidden. Can partitioning errors be the cause? There have been some during OS installation, but I don't remember which exactly

Answer (score 0):

For executing commands I used cmd.exe from Windows XP. When switched to cmd.exe from Windows 7 bug disappeared.